# Represent pseudocode in tabular format

Tags: tables

I want to write my pseudocode in the below tabular format.

[image]

It seems that authors of above pseudocode have used some special latex package. Can anyone help me by either naming the package which has been used or by providing a similar example from where I can start?

Comment: Give me the codez questions aren't all that welcome. Can you supply us with what you've tried thus far? What particular parts are you struggling with?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I am facing problem with writing text Inside table. Like the first line about initialization. I have just started writing code for this but it gives error in first line.

Comment: Try [online](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/)?

Comment: I smell `eqnarray` and abuse of `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variant of Werner's solution. The code also fixes the main errors in the typesetting of the original model and you should be look at it carefully. Note, for instance, the `^{}` bits that are used for setting subscripts at the same level.

Note also the absence of `\left` and `\right` that apparently plagued the original. Look, in particular, at the lines with “col”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\DeclareMathOperator{\col}{col}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\newcommand{\tabindent}{2em}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\centering

\caption{Robust diffusion detection algorithm}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{
  >{\hspace*{\tabindent}}lp{\dimexpr 0.8\textwidth-\tabindent}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{p{0.8\textwidth}}{%
  Initializations: $w_s$, $B_k$, $\alpha_{k,-1}\in\mathbb{R}_{++}^{B_k}$,
  $\hat{R}_{\varphi_{k,-1}}$, $\hat{\varphi}'_{k,-1}$, $\nu_k$,
  $\lambda_k$, $\epsilon$, $\mu_k$. Start with $w_{k,-1}=0$ for
  every node $k$. For every time instant $i\ge 0$, repeat.
}
\\ \addlinespace
&\textbf{Error nonlinearity update:} for every node $k$, repeat

\hspace*{\tabindent}%
  $\!\begin{aligned}
  e_k(i) &= d_k(i)-u_{k,i}w_{k,i-1} \\
  \phi_{k,b}(i) &= \tanh(be_k(i)),\ b=1,\dots,B_k \\
  \varphi_{k,i} &= \col\{\phi_{k,1}(i),\dots,\phi_{k,B_k}(i)\} \\
  \hat{R}_{\varphi_{k,i}} &= \nu_k\hat{R}_{\varphi_{k,i-1}}
    + (1-\nu_k)\varphi_{k,i}^{}\varphi_{k,i}^T \\
  \phi'_{k,b}(i) &= b\sech^2(be_k(i)),\ b=1,\dots,B_k \\
  \varphi'_{k,i} &= \col\{\phi'_{k,1}(i),\dots,\phi'_{k,B_k}(i)\} \\
  \hat{\varphi}'_{k,i} &= \nu_k\varphi'_{k,i-1}+(1-\nu_k)\varphi'_{k,i} \\
  \delta_{k,i} &= 2(\hat{R}_{\varphi_{k,i}}\alpha_{k,i-1}-\varphi'_{k,i}) \\
  \lambda_{k,i} &= \lambda_k
    \frac{\min\{\alpha_{k,i-1}(b),\ 1\le b\le B)k\}}{\lVert\delta_{k,i}\rVert+\epsilon} \\
  \alpha_{k,i} &= \alpha_{k,i-1}-\lambda_k(i)\delta_{k,i} \\
  h_k(i) &= \alpha_{k,i}^T\varphi_{k,i}^{}
  \end{aligned}$
\\ \addlinespace
&\textbf{Incremental update:} for every node $k$, repeat

\hspace*{\tabindent}%
$\psi_{k,i}^{}=w_{k,i-1}^{}+\mu_ku_{k,i}^Th_k^{}(i)$
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should be a sufficient starter.

We create a virtual two-column table. The "first column" is a space of `3em` that's inserted in front of every row to make it look like the text follows from a second column (there are other ways of doing this as well):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{A table caption}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\hspace{3em}}p{.8\linewidth}@{}}
    \toprule
    \unskip Initialization: This is where the pseudocode initialization is supposed to go.
    It may span several lines within the \texttt{tabular}. \\
    \textbf{Error nonlinearity update:} Some content \\[.25\normalbaselineskip]
    \centering\arraybackslash
    $\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
      \begin{array}{r>{{}}l}
        f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
        g(x) &= f(x) \\
        h(x) &= \displaystyle \frac{a}{e}
      \end{array}$ \\
    \textbf{Incremental update:} Some content \\
    \qquad $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ \\
    \textbf{Diffusion update:} Some content \\
    \qquad $g(x) = f(x)$ \\
    \textbf{Decision:} Some content \\
    \qquad $h(x) = \frac{a}{e}$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Apart from that it's like setting regular text within the document. The advantage is we're using a fixed-width `p`aragraph column, which allows for `\centering` of content, if needed.